# Elements in xlsread output MATLAB version R2018a

Tags: matlab, function

I am trying to understand the function that Matlab executes for importing data from excel file.

The very first function in the script generated from import command is the following:

> %% Import the data
>
> [~, ~, raw] =
>   xlsread('C:\Users\gtsutskiridze\Documents\MATLAB\G10XRATE.XLS','g10xrate','A2:J6238')
>   raw(cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(x) && isnumeric(x) && isnan(x),raw)) = {''}

I have read the help file for xlsread and it says the following:

> [NUM,TXT,RAW]=xlsread(FILE) reads data from the first worksheet in the
>   Microsoft
>       Excel spreadsheet file named FILE and returns the numeric data in array NUM.
>       Optionally, returns the text fields in cell array TXT, and the unprocessed data
>       (numbers and text) in cell array RAW.

My question is the following: What do does **~** mean in the output of the xlsread  [~, ~, raw] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the documentation, the xlsread command will give you 3 outputs: NUM, TXT, and RAW. The tilde symbol **~** in `[~,~,RAW]` means that you are not assigning a name to the first two outputs but are only interested in RAW. If for example you were interested in only the first and the third part of the output of the command, you'd use `[NUM,~,RAW] = xlsread(...)`.

It's a useful tool in various cases due to being faster (depending on the general setting of your code), but also because you don't get variables in your workspace that you are not interested in. Check [this](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/357454-what-does-the-tilde-in-the-following-code-mean) for more info.